# combinatorics: give an upper bound for the cardinality of a set of 100-ary sequences

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $S$ be a $1990$-element set and let $P$ be a set of $100$-ary sequences $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{100})$, where $a_i$'s are distinct elements of $S$. An ordered pair $(x,y)$ of elements of $S$ is said to *appear* in $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{100})$ if $x=a_i$ and $y=a_j$, for some $i,j$ with $1\le i<j\le100$. Assume that every ordered pair $(x,y)$ of elements of $S$ appears in at most one member in $P$. Show that $\left | P \right | \le800$.

I'm stuck, can you give me a hint ?

Comment: You say you're stuck, what is it that you tried?

Comment: @Colbi I need a reasoning...that's way I asked for a hint

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ has $1990$ elements there can be at most $1990 \times 1989 = 3958110$ possible ordered pairs. Now one $100$-ary sequence generates $\frac{100 \times 99}{2} = 4950$ ordered pairs. Now as each ordered pair appears in at most one element of $P$ it follows that the number of ordered pairs in $P$ is: $\mid P \mid \times 4950$. From all this we have:

$$\mid P \mid \times 4950 \le 3958110 \implies \mid P \mid \le \frac{3958110}{4950} = 799.61(18) < 800$$

So we have that the cardinality of $P$ under the given conditions is less than $800$.

Comment: Good answer...you wrote "ordered" pairs so I think you should not divide by $2$, therefore following your reasoning we end up with $\left | P \right | \le 800$

Comment: Instead 4950 is correct

Comment: @user348223 Yeah you're correct. I made a mistake. We shouldn't divide the first number by 2.